Why does filter: invert(100%) interfere with position: fixed?
The following snippet contains a text that is fixed to the canvas and therefore does not overlap the main body text (which is offset by the paragraph margin).
But if I use a filter: invert(100%) CSS rule to produce a dark mode effect, the fixed positioning is lost: The fixed text then seems fixed to the body instead of the canvas and therefore overlaps the main text.
You can reproduce it by clicking the button below.


body.darkmode {
  background-color: black;
  filter: invert(100%);
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
<div>Fixed to canvas</div>
<p>Main body text</p>
<button onclick="document.body.classList.toggle('darkmode')">Toggle dark mode</button>



Why does the filter: invert(100%) interfere in this way with the position: fixed? I observed the behavior on Chrome as well as Firefox.
Addendum after reading the answer
The following works:


html.darkmode {
  background-color: white;
  filter: invert(100%);
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
<div>Fixed to canvas</div>
<p>Main body text</p>
<button onclick="document.documentElement.classList.toggle('darkmode')">Toggle dark mode</button>




Check out this answer for a quote from the CSS (draft) specification on the why.
